# Method call unexpected behaviour on UI

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to learn how to call methods throughout a `Wpf` application.

In a basic experiment, I have two pages, `PageData` and `MainPage`.

`PageData` code:

```
namespace AppName
{
    public sealed partial class PageData 
    {
        public PageData()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        // works
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mTest();
        }

        public bool mTest()
        {
            var newTbx = new TextBox{
                Text = "Hello",
                FontSize = 50
                };

            Grid.SetRow(newTbx, 3);
            Grid.SetColumn(newTbx, 3);
            gridMainPageData.Children.Add(newTbx);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage` code:

```
namespace AppName
{
    public sealed class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             PageData passCall = new PageData();

             mDisplayAlert(passCall.mTest().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the method `mTest()` completes because I get the "true" response when `MainPage` loads (I have a method `mDisplayAlert` that I use for showing messages on the `MainPage` UI), but the UI on `PageData` does not change.  I know that `mTest()` works because the button click event on `PageData` does work.

Why does the UI not update when called from MainPage?

Comment: When you talk about a `C#/XAML` app you mean `Wpf app` right ?

Comment: I specified Windows 8 C#/XAML rather than WPF because there appear to be some differences given the Win RT ecosystem.  You obviously know more and I am still learning the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you create a new instance of `PageData` inside `MainPage` when what you really want to do is use the same instance to access the exact same controls. When you call the `.test()` method you create a totally new `TextBox` and assign data to a totally new `Grid` when you think you are writing on you first `PageData` instance.

You have many options from there. You can :

- Pass a reference of the `PageData` instance to you other form when you create it.
- Create an event between the two classes with a reference to the `PageData` instance.
- Make your method and controls `Static` in `PageData` to make sure the whole program share the same instance. (Not recommanded at all)
- If you want a little work around, you can always set you method to `Static` and create a `Static` copy of the control's instance. Then the compiler will ask for a reference of a `Static` control and you can assign the instance copy using `Controls.Find(yourControl)`.(Not a good practice either).

Personally i'd use option number 1 but now you know you have the choice.